# RegEx for matching URLs in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have this example string:

```
line = '[text] something - https://www.myurl.com/test1/ lorem ipsum https://www.myurl.com/test2/ - https://www.myurl.com/test3/ marker needle - some more text at the end'
```

I need to extract the path (without slashes) before "marker needle". The following works to list all paths:

```
print re.findall('https://www\\.myurl\\.com/(.+?)/', line)
# ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
```

However, when I change it to only find the path I want (the one before "marker needle"), it gives a weird output:

```
print re.findall('https://www\\.myurl\\.com/(.+?)/ marker needle', line)
# ['test1/ lorem ipsum https://www.myurl.com/test2/ - https://www.myurl.com/test3']
```

My expected output:

```
test3
```

I have tried the same with `re.search` but the result is the same.

Comment: `.` matches any char, use `[^/]`, `re.findall(r'https://www\.myurl\.com/([^/]+)/ marker needle', line)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew won't it only match up to the slash because I'm using `?` for non-greedy matching?

Comment: No, because non-greedy pattern will be expanded as many times as necessary to obtain a valid match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ah I see, thank you.

Comment: https://regex101.com is your friend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression has three capturing groups, where the second one has our desired output:

```
(https:\/\/www.myurl.com\/)([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(\/\smarker needle)
```

[This tool](https://regex101.com/r/RzqJDl/1) helps us to modify/change the expression, if you wish.

[image]

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Python Test

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re

string = "[text] something - https://www.myurl.com/test1/ lorem ipsum https://www.myurl.com/test2/ - https://www.myurl.com/test3/ marker needle - some more text at the end"
expression = r'(https:\/\/www.myurl.com\/)([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(\/\smarker needle)'
match = re.search(expression, string)
if match:
    print("YAAAY! \"" + match.group(2) + "\" is a match  ")
else: 
    print(' Sorry! No matches!')
```

#### Output

```
YAAAY! "test3" is a match
```

#### Performance Test

This snippet returns the runtime of a 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
const repeat = 10;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const regex = /(.*)(https:\/\/www.myurl.com\/)([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(\/\smarker needle)(.*)/gm;
 const str = "[text] something - https://www.myurl.com/test1/ lorem ipsum https://www.myurl.com/test2/ - https://www.myurl.com/test3/ marker needle - some more text at the end";
 const subst = `$3`;

 var match = str.replace(regex, subst);
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```